# Objectify - getting children of a given parent using get?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I'm trying to get all the children of a given parent key. I can achieve this using the query/ancestor methods as follows:

```
List<Tire> list= ofy.query(Tire.class).ancestor(new    Key<Car(Car.class,carID))).list();
```

The problem with this is that it the query method doesn't go through the cache. How can I get the same list using get?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a keys-only query, then perform a get() for the keys.  This still hits the datastore, but it can reduce your costs to 1 read op + 1 small op per fetch (instead of 1 read op + 1 read op per fetch).

If you use Objectify4, it does this for you automatically (see the Query.hybrid() method).

Comment: Officially, no.  But there's no reason not to use the 4.0a4 version - unless you're using some of the more advanced features, it's quite stable.

Comment: @stickfigure: about Objectify4 and why we'd love to use it but we are not: no maven repo, docs not finished, seems(?) to be backwards incompatible. Any advice on migrating from 3.1?

Comment: Docs are almost complete.  The biggest missing piece is the "how to upgrade from 3.1" document.  And it will be in Maven Central soon.  But yeah, I acknowledge that it's taking a long time.

Comment: Follow up question.. how efficient is a key-only query that filters by an ancestor's key? Something like:

Comment: ofy.query(Car.class).ancestor(someKey).fetchKeys();